# Oracle DB Java Stored Procedure: line starting with hash sign #

Tags: oracle, java-stored-procedures

I have inherited an old Oracle 12c database, which I'm running on a local Oracle 19c server. The database contains the following [Java Stored Procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDEV/chfive.htm#JJDEV13637)

```
create or replace and compile java source named fill_share_content as
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Fill_Share_Content
{
  public static void execute(String directory) throws SQLException
  {
    File path = new File( directory );
    String[] list = path.list();
    String separator = path.separator;

    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
    {
      String filename = list[i];
      File datei = new File( directory + separator + filename );
      if ( datei.isFile() )
      {
        Timestamp filedate = new Timestamp( datei.lastModified() );
        #sql { insert into Share_Content (filename, filedate) values (:filename, :filedate) };
      }
    }
  }
};
/
```

The problem occurs when attempting to execute the statement to create and compile the Java SP: line 20

```
#sql { insert into Share_Content (filename, filedate) values (:filename, :filedate) };
```

throws an error

> error: illegal character: '#'

Generally I am able to create, compile and execute Java Stored Procedures on the database. Questions:

1. What is the meaning of the line starting with the hash sign? I am not familiar with such a construct in Java, something specific to Java stored procedures in Oracle?
2. How can I get I create and compile the Java stored procedure? Allegedly the code is already running on another instance, so the code should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is SQLJ and is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JSQLJ/overview.htm#JSQLJ136).

However, from Oracle 12.2, [Oracle does not support running SQLJ](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/upgrd/desupported-features-oracle-database-12c-r2.html#GUID-219C5674-6F2C-4051-A61B-919DA4FF3CB6).

You need to convert the SQLJ code to JDBC if you want to run it in Oracle 19.

This should give you a start:

```sql
CREATE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED fill_share_content as
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver;

public class Fill_Share_Content
{
  public static void execute(String directory) throws SQLException
  {
    Connection con = null; 
    try {  
      OracleDriver ora = new OracleDriver(); 
      con = ora.defaultConnection(); 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      return;
    }
    Timestamp filedate = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
      "insert into Share_Content (filename, filedate) values (:filename, :filedate)"
    );
    ps.setString(1, directory);
    ps.setTimestamp(2, filedate);
    ps.execute();
  }
};
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=44209ad02e43c6596fb0a1819243f78e)*